# IIS loghttp module spams EventLog with errors about a worker process which cannot obtain custom log data for N requests

Tags: iis, event-log, iis-10, application-pool

we have setup our web application on a new Windows Server Datacenter 2019 edition.
Previously it ran on a Windows 2008 server.

The application runs smoothly, but the EventLog is being overflooded with these errors:

```
The loghttp module in the worker process with id '13104' could not obtain custom log data for '1' requests. The data field contains the error code.

The loghttp module in the worker process with id '11500' could not obtain custom log data for '1' requests. The data field contains the error code.

The loghttp module in the worker process with id '13536' could not obtain custom log data for '1' requests. The data field contains the error code.
```

We have a bunch of AppPools running, but the errors only comes in relation to 3 of them.
The relevant ones are identified via the worker process id, see below screendump.
[Pattern, logs every minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uk4f.png)

If I stop the IIS Logging Module the EventLogs also stops.
There are no Custom Fields being logged.
The Logging module is using w3c-format with only Standard fields added.

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR shows nothing besides lines like this:

```
2021-11-02 09:10:58 10.217.24.201 34241 10.217.10.240 443 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2021-11-02 09:10:58 10.217.24.201 5601 10.217.10.240 443 - - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

IIS Logs are being written to file OK.

There is a pattern in the log, so every minute the same 5-6 EventLogs-lines are written
[Pattern with logs every minute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnjZM.png)

Comment: Maybe something wrong with the application pool. Have you tried to create a new application pool?